# Extending Schema - New attributes and new classes

Tags: active-directory

If I add my new attribute to the User class then I'm able to update it using a simple script. However if I create a new class with new attributes I'm unable to update it, I get:

```
Active Directory: The requested operation did not satisfy one or more 
 constraints associated with the class of the object.
```

The issue is solved if I add the attribute provisionally on User Class and the remove it but I have a lot of new attributes contained into four new classes.  So I think I'm missing some step.

The classes and attributes are active.

This is how I'm updating the attribute:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Pepe Perez,CN=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=com") 
objUser.myDescription="D"
objUser.SetInfo
```

Any clues.

Regards,
m0dest0.

Comment: Which Kind of class do you create (structural or auxiliary) ? Can you show how you use your new classes (your code) ?

Comment: @JPBlanc - There are of both types.

Comment: @JPBlanc - I added the code how I'm updating the attributes. Please keep in mind the code is the same as on live or production system, basically I'm extending my local schema to match the one from production. thank you.

Comment: myDescription is your new attribute. I think it's part an auxikiary class. Don't you forgot to register this auxiliary part into the schema user class ?

Comment: @JPBlanc, there are structural classes, in this case how I could register them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `myDescription` is part of a structural class, this means that `CN=Pepe Perez,CN=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=com` is an object of this structural class (attribute `objectClass`). If it's not the case it can explain the message you got.